# Laravel Factories with Intermediate Tables

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create a factory for a BlogPost model.

A blog post `belongsToMany` `Tag` and vice versa.

There is an intermediate table (`blog_post_tag`) to store the relations of blogposts to tags.

I would like to seed a blog post with a number of tag names.

How can one seed a DB using factories and intermediate tables?

May have an answer [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#pivot-table-attributes)

So I can add the following below to my BlogPost seeder. This would also create tags, but I would like to get existing tags (preferably 3-5 and only if any exist).

`hasAttached()` accepts a factory as the first argument so this will not work.

```
BlogPost::factory()
            ->hasAttached(
                Tag::factory()->count(3)
            )
            ->create();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fill my relations with existing data:

```php
<?php
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Alpha;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

use App\Models\Beta;
use App\Models\Gamma;

class AlphaFactory extends Factory {
    protected $model = Alpha::class;

    public function definition() {
        $beta_ids = Beta::all()->pluck('id');
        $gamma_ids = Gamma::all()->pluck('id');

        return [
            'name' => Str::slug($this->faker->unique()->realText(50)),
            'number' => $this->faker->randomNumber(3),
            'beta_id' => $this->faker->randomElement($beta_ids),
            'gamma_id' => $this->faker->randomElement($gamma_ids)
        ];
    }
}
```

If you want to be fancy and create sometimes new entries to relate to:

```php
<?php
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Alpha;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

use App\Models\Beta;

class AlphaFactory extends Factory {
    protected $model = Alpha::class;

    public function definition() {
        $beta_id;
        $beta_ids = Beta::all()->pluck('id');
        if($beta_ids->isEmpty() || $this->faker->boolean($chanceOfGettingTrue = 50)) {
            $beta_id = Beta::factory()->create()->id;
        } else {
            $beta_id = $this->faker->randomElement($beta_ids);
        }

        return [
            'name' => Str::slug($this->faker->unique()->realText(50)),
            'number' => $this->faker->randomNumber(3),
            'beta_id' => $beta_id
        ];
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the right way to do this, but it works for me. If there is a better way, let me know.